# Firestore cloud function cant find document to update

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create an online presence feature that updates each user's online status using flutter. I am achieving this by using a realtime database, cloud functions, and cloud Firestore.

My problem is when I run my cloud function to detect changes in the realtime database and update the status field in my user's collection in cloud Firestore. It keeps saying it cannot find the document to update.

Here is my cloud function code

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

const firestore = admin.firestore();

exports.onUserStatusChange = functions.database
  .ref("/{uid}/status")
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    // Get the data written to Realtime Database
    const isOnline = change.after.val();

    // Then use other event data to create a reference to the
    // corresponding Firestore document.
    const userStatusFirestoreRef = firestore.doc(`users/${context.params.uid}`);
    
    console.log(`status: ${isOnline}`);

    return userStatusFirestoreRef.update({
      status: isOnline,
      last_seen: Date.now(),
    });
  });
```

here is the error on onUserStatusChange function

```
Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: No document to update: projects/posweepay/databases/(default)/documents/users/162057431950849
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:176:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:342:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:305:181)
    at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:124:78
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
```

Realtime database structure

[image: Realtime database structure]

Cloud Firestore database structure

[image: Cloud Firestore database structure]

Comment: can u do console.log(context.params.uid)?

Comment: where do i view the logs?

Comment: i dont think i can see it in my flutter debug console

Comment: im using vscode

Comment: in the firebase console you can see the logs

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: It seems you try to update a user with an id corresponding to the value of the `accountId` field, i.e. 162057431950849

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail how you are invoking this function and what you expect it to do.  Please be specific and provide values that we can actually track through your system.   There should be enough information in your question that anyone can use the reproduce the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

From the logs, it looks like you're trying to refer to the document from the `user.accountid` rather than using the document identifier.

While the `accountid` might be `162057431950849` (I'm guessing this happens to be the UID of the document in your Realtime Database) - the actual identifier for the document in Firestore is `615862116620550`.

This seems like a discrepancy in your data model. A possible solution could be to store the Firestore Document UID in your Realtime Database and use that value to refer to the Firestore Document whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

While at first glance the UIDs in the screenshots are the same, the error message seems to indicate that there is some mismatch.

To troubleshoot, I recommend using a set-and-merge operation, which will also *create* the document if it doesn't exist:

```
return userStatusFirestoreRef.set({
  status: isOnline,
  last_seen: Date.now(),
}, { merge: true });
```

With this you can check what new document gets created, and how it compares to the existing document that you expected to be updated.